# How to set column order by Drag Drop in Kendo UI TreeList Widget?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-treelist

I am using Angularjs version of Kendo UI Tree List Widget. Below is the code that I am using

**HTML**

```
 <div id="treeview" kendo-tree-list="treelist" 
 k-options="TreeViewOptions" style="margin-top: 5px" class="trade_show">
 </div>
```

Code for binding the Tree List

```
 var treeDataSource = new kendo.data.TreeListDataSource({
    data: [
        { id: 1, Name: "Main Menu", Icon: "", View: "", parentId: null },
        { id: 5, Name: "Sub Menu 1", Icon: "", View: "", parentId: 1 },
        { id: 6, Name: "Sub Menu 2", Icon: "", View: "", parentId: 1 },
        { id: 7, Name: "Sub Menu 3", Icon: "", View: "", parentId: 1 },
    ],
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "id",
            expanded: true
        }
    }
});

$scope.TreeViewOptions = {
    dataSource: treeDataSource,
    height: 540,
    editable: {
        move: true
    },
    sortable: true,
    columns: [
         { field: "Name" },
        { field: "Icon" },
        { field: "View" }
    ]
};
```

Every thing is working fine, but I am unable to get column ordering working. Essentially what I need is to be able to drag drop the rows to set their display order.

This feature exists in Kendo UI TreeView widget. 
Is this feature supported in the Kendo UI Tree List Widget?
If not, then is there a workaround to get it working?

Comment: You can only apply sorting to rows. Drag and drop options are only for the column position.